# Javascript does not work in Django templates with foundation 6

Tags: javascript, django, zurb-foundation

I have these scripts loaded to my template

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jQuery.min.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.core.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.reveal.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.util.touch.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.util.triggers.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.util.motion.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.util.box.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/foundation.util.keyboard.js' %}"></script>
```

Anyways, my Foundation modals do not work. When I click the button made for this purpose, it doesn not do anything.

The repo if you want to  test it: https://github.com/RodrigEEz/PersonalBlog

Comment: Have you loaded static at the top of your file? {% load static %}

Comment: In your index.html you have loaded static files before the html page starts. Load it after your file starts